# How Can I Model Multiple Short Time Series Samples?

Tags: time-series, panel-data

How Can I Model Multiple Short Time Series Samples?

For example, let's say I have a new subject each month, and I measure each subject every day for the entire month. I then want to model these multiple strings of independent time series because I assume that there is an underlying pattern that applies to all 12 subjects. However, a time series with an n of 30 is too short to model, so is there some way to group these 12 time series together for a parallel analysis?

I imagine the way to handle this is similar to how one might handle a time series with multiple breaks of unknown length. Unfortunately, I unaware of how to deal with this type of data structure.

Any thoughts on where to even begin? What terms I should research?

Comment: Data structures like that are sometimes called 'panel data'. They can e.g. be modelled by mixed effects models with within-subject AR structure.